# Hide table row (tr) with elements on button click

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

```
<tbody>
                @if (pr_parts != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var part in pr_parts)
                    {
                        
                        <tr onclick="var s = this.parentNode.querySelector('tr.selected'); s && s.classList.remove('selected'); this.classList.add('selected');">
                            <td>@part.Part_ID</td>
                            <td>@part.Part_Number</td>
                           
                            <td>@part.Part_Description</td>
                            <td>@part.Part_Manufacturer</td>
                            <td><input for="Stock_Quantity" class="form-control" @bind="@part.Move_Quantity" /></td>
                            <td>@part.location</td>
                            @* @if (part.Shelf_Location != "PVIRTUAL")
                                {
                                    <td>@part.Shelf_Location</td>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <td></td>
                                }
                            *@
                            <td>@to</td>
                            <td>
                                <InputSelect id="Shelf_Location" @bind-Value="part.Move_Shelf_Location">
                                    @if (wip_e == null && wip_o == null)
                                                {
                                        <option>None Available</option>
                                                }
                                                else if ((wip_e != null && wip_e.Count() > 0) && (wip_o == null || wip_o.Count() < 1))
                                                {
                                        <option> </option>
                                        @foreach (var shelf in wip_e)
                                                    {
                                            <option value="@shelf.Shelf_Location">@shelf.Shelf_Location</option>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else if (wip_o != null && wip_o.Count() > 0)
                                                {
                                        <option> </option>
                                        @foreach (var shelf in wip_o)
                                                    {
                                            <option value="@shelf.Shelf_Location">@shelf.Shelf_Location</option>
                                                    }
                                        @foreach (var shelf in wip_e)
                                                    {
                                            <option value="@shelf.Shelf_Location">@shelf.Shelf_Location</option>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                </InputSelect>
                            </td>
                            <td>@part.category</td>
                            @*<td><input for="comments" class="form-control" @bind="@part.comments" /></td>*@
                            @*<td><i class="fa fa-times-circle" id="drop_remove" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-check-circle" id="drop_add" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>*@
                            @*<td><button id="hide" class="btn btn-secondary buttonInactive" @onclick="@ShowAlert">Hide</button></td>
                                <td><button id="show" class="btn btn-secondary buttonInactive" @onclick="@ShowAlert">Show</button></td>*@
                        </tr>

                    }
                }
 </tbody>
```

I am new to blazor and I am running into a few challenges, I would like to hide or show elements in a row with a button click but when doing so with private bool IsShow { get; set; } = false;
private void Show()
{`enter code here`
IsShow = !IsShow;
}

it hides all the rows which is not what I want. Please help

Comment: You know if you break every thing out inside your for loops into separate components they get there own separate state management.... SOLID

Comment: @BrianParker Would that help if I want to single out individual rows if I want to hide or show them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div hidden="@Show">
    <h1> Test </h1>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Hide">Hide</button>

@code{
public bool Show = false;

    public void Hide()
    {

        Show = !Show;

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it hides all elements in the table row(tr) and I would like to hide/show only selected elements in table row (tr)

Comment: @Gary No it hides whatever elements you attach ` hidden="@Show"` to. If you put it on the `<tr>` element then yes, it will hide the entire row. I think we need to know how you want to determine which elements in the row should be hidden or shown. Another way would be to wrap an `@if` around the cells in the row. `<tr> @if(Show){ <td></td>} </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what @A N posted. You can use the "hidden"-Attribute to hide HTML-Elements. You can obviously use the same boolean to hide multiple elements at the same time:

```
<div hidden=@HideElements>
    <p hidden=@HideElements>This is some text that can be hidden...</p>
    <table hidden=@HideElements>
        <tr>
            <td hidden=@HideElements>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            @* and so on ... *@
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick=@ToggleVisibility >Toggle elements</button>
</div>

@code
{
    public bool HideElements { get; set; } = false;

    public void ToggleVisibility(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        HideElements = !HideElements;
    }
}
```

But of course you can always hide different elements with different booleans to the extend of you imagination and beyond.